# Can a particle be entangled with itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose I had a *single* particle with a four-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ spanned by the states $\{ |1\rangle,|2\rangle,|3\rangle,|4\rangle\}$ and suppose I prepared the particle in the superposition state

$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|1\rangle + |4\rangle \right). $$

With a trivial relabelling of the basis states as $|1\rangle \rightarrow |00\rangle$, $|2\rangle \rightarrow |01\rangle$, $|3\rangle \rightarrow |10\rangle$ and $|4\rangle \rightarrow |11\rangle$, then it makes it clear that the original Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is isomorphic to the Hilbert space of a *pair* of spin-$1/2$ particles as $\mathcal{H} \cong \mathcal{H}_{1/2} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1/2} $, where $\mathcal{H}_{1/2}$ is spanned by the basis $\{ |0\rangle , |1\rangle \}$.

In this basis, the state $|\psi\rangle$ can be trivially rewritten as

$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle + |11\rangle \right),$$

which is a Bell state - a maximally entangled state of two particles. Well, in the original basis, we have a superposition state of a single particle, whilst in the binary basis we can view it as an entangled state of two particles.

### My questions

It would seem as though the original particle is entangled with itself, but it feels like I am cheating as it is simply a result of changing our interpretation of the basis states, so my questions are:

1. Can a particle be entangled with itself?
2. If so, does this entanglement have any physical significance? For example, could it be used for quantum computing?

Comment: Some would call any *superposition* of states an entangled state, but this is mostly a trivial case from the point of view of practical applications of entanglement. Notation of course doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, I'd say the meaning of our model (e.g. "choice" of Hilbert space; recall that they are all isomorphic) depends on the *physical* observables; so a four-dimensional vector space can be the state of e.g. a particle on a lattice with four sites or the Hilbert space of two qubits, for example. The meaning is determined by the physical experiments we want to model.

Comment: Particles are entangled when their state cannot be described as the tensor product of states, each in a single-particle Hilbert space. The physical significance of entanglement in, say, secure quantum communication,  also rests heavily on the spacial separation of two entangled particles (see Anton Zeilinger's experiments). I find the question if a particle can be entangled with itself of little physical significance.

Comment: There were papers claiming that e.g. the s-wave state of a single electron is an entangled state between left and right half-space, but I always found this rather obscure. As the other comments say, there is a physical meaning to entanglement, which generally involves a tensor product and locality.

Comment: there are valid arguments to be made that a single particle in a superposition of different spatial modes ought to be considered "entangled". For example because such superpositions can (in principle) always be converted into entanglement, hence they're "fundamentally the same thing". A standard reference is van Enk's paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your isomorphism is not an isomorphism of the relevant structures.

The state space of a quantum system with many particles is a Hilbert space **together** with a tensor product decomposition of that Hilbert space.  In the case of one particle on a lattice with four sites, the state space is a four-dimensional Hilbert space with the trivial decomposition.  In the case of two qubits, the state space is a four-dimensional Hilbert space presented as a tensor product of two two-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

One four-dimensional Hilbert space is isomorphic to another, but not in a way that respects the given decompositions.